# Best practice for regex to match repetition

Tags: regex

I wanted to know which one is more efficient way to match a double or triple (or so on) occurrence, like in url:

```
http://domain.com
```

if I want to match the double slashes "//", which one is more efficient:

This:

```
\/\/
```

Or this

```
\/{2}
```

Imagine this for some lengthier and complex scenarios, and then suggest which way would be more efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: For a single character, not requiring a backslash, the literal form might be preferable, especially when being enclosed by other literal matches. Otherwise, use the `{2}`…

Comment: i tried it on literal characters too and seems like {2} is still faster! :/ any explanation?

Comment: It’s unlikely to have a significant difference at all for this little case. If you experience such difference, you should question your method of benchmarking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use:

```
(?:pattern}{2}
```

for these reasons:

1. You don't want to repeat a lengthy pattern
2. range performs better as regex engine doesn't need to process same pattern twice
3. Easy to extend range to `{4}` or `{5,10}` etc but doing same is not easy with repetitions

Check these 2 demo links to corroborate on performance part:

- [Using Range of `{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/dK7pV6/1) - taking 29 steps
- [Repeating pattern](https://regex101.com/r/dK7pV6/2) - taking 47 steps